# Bubble Sort C - Linked List

Tags: c, bubble-sort

So here is the problem I am having with my small bubble sort function. I am able to sort the value however I always get a cutoff after 3 nodes. An example would be:

Sort the following:

3
2
54
5
4

I always get(from smallest being the head):

2
3
4

And that's it, nothing else.

```
 void sortByLine (struct lnode** head) {
      int count = 1;
  while(count){
      struct lnode *temp =*head;
    count = 0;
    while(temp != NULL){
        struct lnode *next = nodeGetNext(temp);
        if(next != NULL){           
           if((lineCmp(temp,next)) > 0 ){
            swap(head, next,temp);
            count = 1;
           }
        }
        temp = nodeGetNext(temp);
    }
}
```

}

Line Cmp Function:

```
int lineCmp (struct lnode* n1, struct lnode* n2) {
  int node1 = nodeGetLine(n1);
  int node2 = nodeGetLine(n2);

  if(node1 == node2){
      return 0;
  }
  else if(node1 > node2){
      return 1;
  }
  else
      return -1;
```

}

Swap Function:

```
 void swap (struct lnode** head, struct lnode* n1, struct lnode* n2) {
    struct lnode *prevn1 = nodeGetPrev(*head, n1);   
    struct lnode *prevn2 = nodeGetPrev(*head, n2);

  struct lnode *nextn1 = nodeGetNext(n1);
  struct lnode *nextn2 = nodeGetNext(n2);   

  if(prevn2 == n1 && prevn1 == NULL){
      evictNode(head, n2);
      pushNode(head, n2);
  }
  else if(prevn1 == n2 && prevn2 == NULL){
      evictNode(head, n1);
      pushNode(head, n1);
  }
  else if(prevn1 == n2 && nextn1 == NULL){
      evictNode(head, n1);
      insertNode(head, prevn2 , n1);   
  }
  else if(prevn2 == n1 && nextn2 == NULL){
      evictNode(head, n2);
      insertNode(head, prevn1, n2);
  }   
  else{
  evictNode(head, n1);
  evictNode(head, n2);   
  insertNode(head, prevn2 , n1);   
  insertNode(head, prevn1 , n2);
  }
```

}

Comment: we will need to see definitions of swap and linecmp, it looks like you arent handling the next ptr correctly

Comment: Added the new functions. So the pointer is not being pointer correctly to the next node?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the Swap Function: Removing a node can invalidate the previous calculated nodes

```
 void swap (struct lnode** head, struct lnode* n1, struct lnode* n2) {
    struct lnode *prevn1 = nodeGetPrev(*head, n1);   
    struct lnode *prevn2 = nodeGetPrev(*head, n2);

  struct lnode *nextn1 = nodeGetNext(n1);
  struct lnode *nextn2 = nodeGetNext(n2);   

  if(prevn2 == n1 && prevn1 == NULL){
      evictNode(head, n2);
      pushNode(head, n2);
  }
  else if(prevn1 == n2 && prevn2 == NULL){
      evictNode(head, n1);
      pushNode(head, n1);
  }
  else if(prevn1 == n2 && nextn1 == NULL){
      evictNode(head, n1);
      insertNode(head, prevn2 , n1);   
  }
  else if(prevn2 == n1 && nextn2 == NULL){
      evictNode(head, n2);
      insertNode(head, prevn1, n2);
  }   
  else if (n1==prevn2)
  {
       evictNode (head, n1);
       insertNode(head, n2, n1);  
  }
  else if (n2==prevn1)
   {
       evictNode (head, n2);
       insertNode(head, n1, n2);  
   } 
  else {
   evictNode(head, n1);
   evictNode(head, n2);   
   insertNode(head, prevn1, n2);
   insertNode(head, prevn2, n1);
  }
}
```

Comment: @user2085247 IS this helping?